# Help mapping list of class objects using NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, propertygrid

I have a class that contains a list of objects.

I previously had this as type of IList which mapped fine.  However, I was wanting to add the ability to add/remove/edit items in this List via a PropertyGrid control.

I was therefore required to set the List as a type of Collection derived from CollectionBase and that contained a ICustomTypeDescriptor in order for this to work rather than the original IList.

I was wandering if someone could tell me how, or if it will be possible to map this list using this method, or how I can modify my current approach to get the items in the list to be editable via the PropertyGrid.

Here is my CollectionClass, which I'd also like to figure out how to make generic so I could reuse this, but nevertheless here are the two classes which I had to define in order to make the List of objects editable via the PropertyGrid:

```
public class ZoneCollection : CollectionBase, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    #region Collection Implementation

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an zone object to the collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emp"></param>
    public void Add(Zone zone)
    {
        this.List.Add(zone);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes an zone object from the collection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="emp"></param>
    public void Remove(Zone zone)
    {
        this.List.Remove(zone);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an employee object at index position.
    /// </summary>
    public Zone this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Zone)this.List[index];
        }
    }

    #endregion

    // Implementation of interface ICustomTypeDescriptor 
    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor impl

    public String GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public String GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type. Returns properties with certain
    /// attributes. this restriction is not implemented here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Create a collection object to hold property descriptors
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pds = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

        // Iterate the list of employees
        for (int i = 0; i < this.List.Count; i++)
        {
            // Create a property descriptor for the employee item and add to the property descriptor collection
            ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor pd = new ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor(this, i);
            pds.Add(pd);
        }
        // return the property descriptor collection
        return pds;
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CollectionPropertyDescriptor.
/// </summary>
public class ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private ZoneCollection collection = null;
    private int index = -1;

    public ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor(ZoneCollection coll, int idx) :
        base("#" + idx.ToString(), null)
    {
        this.collection = coll;
        this.index = idx;
    }

    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            return new AttributeCollection(null);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.collection.GetType();
        }
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            Zone zone = this.collection[index];
            return zone.ID.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            Zone zone = this.collection[index];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(zone.ID.ToString());

            if ( zone.Streets.Route != String.Empty || zone.Streets.Crossing != String.Empty)
                sb.Append("::");
            if (zone.Streets.Route != String.Empty)
                sb.Append(zone.Streets.Route);
            if ( zone.Streets.Crossing != String.Empty)
            {
                sb.Append(" and ");
                sb.Append(zone.Streets.Crossing);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this.collection[index];
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "#" + index.ToString(); }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this.collection[index].GetType(); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        // this.collection[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Here is my Zone class:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
[CategoryAttribute("Configuration")]
[Serializable]
public class Zone
{
    #region Private Fields

    private bool active;
    private string dir;
    private Heading heading = new Heading();
    private int id;
    private int intID;
    private Position start = new Position();
    private Position finish = new Position();
    private int width;
    private Position[] corners = new Position[4];
    private Streets streets = new Streets();

    #endregion        

    #region Constructors

    public Zone() 
    {
        if (Program.main != null)
        {
            IntID = Program.main.intID;

            Intersection intersection = Program.data.Intersections.list.Find(
                delegate(Intersection tInt)
                {
                    return tInt.ID == IntID;
                }
            );

            if (intersection != null)
            {
                Streets.Crossing = intersection.Streets.Crossing;
                Streets.Route = intersection.Streets.Route;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public virtual long PK { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set { active = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The direction for the Zone.")]
    public virtual string Dir
    {
        get { return dir; }
        set { dir = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The heading for the Zone.")]
    public virtual Heading Heading
    {
        get { return heading; }
        set { heading = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The Zone Identification Number.")]
    public virtual int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The Identification Number associated with the Priority Detector of the Zone.")]
    public virtual int IntID
    {
        get { return intID; }
        set { intID = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The location of the Zone's Start.")]
    public virtual Position Start
    {
        get { return start; }
        set { start = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The location of the Zone's Finish.")]
    public virtual Position Finish
    {
        get { return finish; }
        set { finish = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The width of the Zone.")]
    public virtual int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual Position[] Corners
    {
        get { return corners; }
        set { corners = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Configuration"),
        DescriptionAttribute("The streets associated with the Zone."),
        DisplayName("Zone Streets")]
    public virtual Streets Streets
    {
        get { return streets; }
        set { streets = value; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And here is my original mapping of the list of the Zone class objects contained within my Intersection class:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="EMTRAC.Devices.Device, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="`Device`" lazy="false">
  <id name="PK" type="System.Int64, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    <column name="PK" />
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <many-to-one class="EMTRAC.Connections.Connection, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="LocalConnection" lazy="false" cascade="all">
    <column name="LocalConnection_id" />
  </many-to-one>
  <many-to-one class="EMTRAC.Connections.Connection, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Connection" lazy="false" cascade="all">
    <column name="Connection_id" />
  </many-to-one>
  <many-to-one class="EMTRAC.Packets.Packet, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Configuration" lazy="false" cascade="all">
    <column name="Configuration_id" />
  </many-to-one>
  <joined-subclass name="EMTRAC.Intersections.Intersection, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" lazy="false">
    <key>
      <column name="Device_id" />
    </key>
    <bag name="Zones" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key>
        <column name="Intersection_id" />
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="EMTRAC.Zones.Zone, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </bag>
    <many-to-one class="EMTRAC.Intersections.Streets, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Streets" lazy="false" cascade="all">
      <column name="Streets_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one class="EMTRAC.Positions.Position, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="Position" lazy="false" cascade="all">
      <column name="Position" />
    </many-to-one>
  </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

I originally went with a simple bag b/c I was using an IList, but I'm not sure what or how I would do this now that the Zones list is not an IList but rather a ZoneCollection class that derrives from CollectionBase.

I assume it is puking b/c I don't have the ZoneCollection class mapped out, but I don't know how to begin mapping this b/c all the class there is is a list of zones objects.  Do I just map the class and have a bag inside that class?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some options

1: [implementing a NH custom collection](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/12/07/custom-collections-with-nhibernate-part-iii-refactored.aspx)

2: [use an inner collection in your own collection](http://colinjack.blogspot.com/2008/09/nhibernate-mapping-custom-collections.html)

for example

```
class ZoneCollection : IList<Zone>, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    //  Must be defined as an IList and not a List for NHibernate to save correctly
    private IList<Zone> _inner;

    public ZoneCollection()
    {
        _inner = new List<Zone>();
    }

    public int IndexOf(Zone item)
    {
        return _inner.IndexOf(item);
    }

    // ...
}

<component name="Zones" access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
  <bag name="_inner" access="field" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key>
      <column name="Intersection_id" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="EMTRAC.Zones.Zone, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </bag>
</component>
```

Comment: That is actually quite helpful.  I just have one question.  In my situation what would I use for the access property of the component in the mapping and what would be the bag name?

Comment: I can't figure out how to map this using the component declaration mentioned in the Mapping Custom collections reference you mentioned.  I get a no getter/setter for my List error.  Since I derived from CollectionsBase the property Zones is the list itself.  If I don't declare the component and just the bag, when I try to save the object I get an {"Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag' to type 'EMTRAC.Collections.ZoneCollection'."} exception.

Comment: the component thing is only viable if you have an inner IList which you dont have right now, ill edit my answer

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  Don't suppose there's a way to do this deriving from the CollectionsBase?  I'm not sure how to obtain the list from the CollectionsBase in this case.  If not its not a real big deal, it would just prevent me from having to develop the entire interface for the IList.

Comment: there is a way while deriving from CollectionsBase (see link 1) but its additional work too. Additionally having `IList<Zone>` as property is also better because you can decorate your list with additional things, with ZoneCollection not so easy

Comment: Thanks for the reasoning.  I'll work on implementing it as an IList then.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Okay, after implementing the ZonesCollection as deriving from IList<Zone> I had to change the access="property" for my component name="Zones" as the List is being accessed from the Zones property in my Intersection class.  When saving the intersection I get an exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[EMTRAC.Zones.Zone]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EMTRAC.Zones.Zone]'."  Any ideas?

Comment: Think I figured it out.  In the example you posted you declared _inner as a List<Zone> rather than and IList<Zone>.  Changing this resolves the issue and I now have it working thanks to your guidance.  If you'll change that line I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: One last comment while I wait for you to change that line.  This works with NHibernate but then it unfortunately breaks binding the contents of this list within the PropertyGrid again which is a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: I was able to edit your post and change it for you.  I posted a comment explaining the change.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Coming back to this in case someone else runs across this.

I was actually able to achieve the functionality I was looking for but it took some tweaking.

I diverged from the route of using a CustomCollection implementation and in turn used a generic and non-generic implementation of IList in order to be able to completely map the collection with NHibernate as well as display the collection as a property of the base class that is editable via the collection editor.

The mapping itself is quite simple.  We simply define a component, specify the access as a property.  Within the component we define the bag name and we're going to set the access for the bag as a field.  I'd also recommend turning the cascade option to "all-delete-orphan".  Finally, we declare the bag as we normally would with a key and then the class that it contains.  Here is my mapping:

```
     <component name="Zones" access="property">
    <bag name="_list" cascade="all-delete-orphan" access="field" lazy="false">
      <key>
        <column name="Intersection_PK" />
      </key> 
      <one-to-many class="EMTRAC.Zones.Zone, EMTRAC_v3, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </bag>
  </component>
```

Now, the tricky part.  The Property Grid as it turns it is pretty finicky with what it is expecting.

As you may or may not know, mapping a class that implements CollectionBase is no small matter with NHibernate.  So I decided to try and tackle this approach by implementing an IList where Zone would be the object type you are storing in your Collection.

As it turns out, the PropertyGrid control does not like this.  It needs the non-generic IList explicit implementation, not the generic one.  I thought I was going to be okay with my implementation since I was specifying a specific type in this case; however, I was mistaken.

So it turns out I could implement both the generic and non generic IList and that solved all my problems.  I could now map the collection with NHibernate, display the Property within the PropertyGrid control, and edit the Collection via the CollectionEditor that was automatically opening when clicking on the Collection within the PropertyGrid control.  Here is my implementation of the Collection class:

```
    public class ZoneCollection : IList<Zone>, IList, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private IList<Zone> _list = new List<Zone>();

    //private IList _list = new ArrayList();

    public ZoneCollection()
    {
        //_list = new ArrayList();
    }

    public int IndexOf(Zone item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Zone item)
    {
        _list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public Zone this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[index];
        }
        set
        {
            _list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(Zone item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Zone item)
    {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Zone[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList)_list).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(Zone item)
    {
        return _list.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Zone> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        int index = Count;
        Add((Zone)value);
        return index;
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        return Contains((Zone)value);
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return IndexOf((Zone)value);
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        Insert(index, (Zone)value);
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return ((IList)_list).IsFixedSize; }
    }

    bool IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList)_list).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        Remove((Zone)value);
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this[index];
        }
        set
        {
            this[index] = (Zone)value;
        }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        CopyTo((Zone[])array, index);
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)_list).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((ICollection)_list).SyncRoot; }
    }


    // Implementation of interface ICustomTypeDescriptor 
    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor impl

    public String GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public String GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type. Returns properties with certain
    /// attributes. this restriction is not implemented here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attributes"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return GetProperties();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called to get the properties of this type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Create a collection object to hold property descriptors
        PropertyDescriptorCollection pds = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(null);

        // Iterate the list of zones
        for (int i = 0; i < this._list.Count; i++)
        {
            // Create a property descriptor for the zone item and add to the property descriptor collection
            ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor pd = new ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor(this, i);
            pds.Add(pd);
        }
        // return the property descriptor collection
        return pds;
    }

    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CollectionPropertyDescriptor.
/// </summary>
public class ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private ZoneCollection collection = null;
    private int index = -1;

    public ZoneCollectionPropertyDescriptor(ZoneCollection coll, int idx) :
        base("#" + idx.ToString(), null)
    {
        this.collection = coll;
        this.index = idx;

    }

    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get
        {
            return new AttributeCollection(null);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get
        {
            return this.collection.GetType();
        }
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            Zone zone = (Zone)this.collection[index];
            return zone.ID.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            Zone zone = (Zone)this.collection[index];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(zone.ID.ToString());

            if (zone.Streets.Route != String.Empty || zone.Streets.Crossing != String.Empty)
                sb.Append("::");
            if (zone.Streets.Route != String.Empty)
                sb.Append(zone.Streets.Route);
            if (zone.Streets.Crossing != String.Empty)
            {
                sb.Append(" and ");
                sb.Append(zone.Streets.Crossing);
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return this.collection[index];
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "#" + index.ToString(); }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return this.collection[index].GetType(); }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        // this.collection[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Special thanks to Firo for starting me on the right path and Simon Mourier for helping to clarify the rest for me.  Hopefully someone else can benefit from this in the future.